# Create SQL view column from result set

Tags: sql, view, procedure

I'm new to SQL and attempting to revise a Create View script to add a new column from a select statement result set I've googled this quite a bit but haven't seen a good example.

Here's the select statement:

```
select lease_id, year(posting_date) as years1, SUM(amount) as Annual 
from la_tbl_lease_projection
group by year(posting_date), lease_id
order by lease_id
```

The complicating factor is this. The Annual column  in the result set is the Annual sum of expenses for a lease_id. However, in the view I'm adding the column to, expenses are listed monthly. So lease_id 100001 has 12 lines in 2010, 2011, etc. I want the view to have the new column show the Annual amount on each of the 12 monthly line items. The new Annual column should be to the right of the amount column and each line should contain the sum of the amount column for that year. e.g.:

```
Lease_id      Posting_Date         Amount        Annual

100001        2010-01-01             $25           $300

100001        2010-02-01             $25           $300

etc...............
```

The view I'm adding to is a reasonably complex join and union from multiple tables. Instead of creating a new table for my result set, I'd like to access it using a stored procedure, unless there's a better option. MSDN says temp tables and table variables don't work in views so that's not an option.

I think this can be done by something like "when years1 = years1 AND lease_id = lease_id then [Annual] = resultset total, but can't seem to visualize it. Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were looking at MSDN, I'm assuming SQL Server for this answer;

To get a yearly column that's a by year sum of amounts, you can use `SUM() OVER ()`;

```
SELECT *, SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Posting_Date)) Yearly
FROM la_tbl_lease_projection;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/42687/1).

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! I added lease_id to the Partition By so that it would total the amounts by year AND lease and it works like a charm. I still need to do the join in the view but I should be able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think a derived table would do the trick for you something like:

```
select blah, blah2, blah3, ..., a.annual
from
<Long complicated set of joins>
join
  (select lease_id, year(posting_date) as years1, SUM(amount) as Annual 
  from la_tbl_lease_projection
  group by year(posting_date), lease_id
  order by lease_id) a 
    on sometable.lease_id = a.lease_id and year(sometable .posting_date) = a.years1
Where <complex where conditions>
```